# SMS date routing with Twilio function and airtable

Tags: routes, twilio, sms, twilio-api, airtable

Thank you in advance for any support! I'm a first time user of this community!

Each day I send an SMS message to a list of respondents (this is already working). I'd like to use a Twilio function to look up an Airtable base each day in order to evaluate the response to the original message.

My sense is the following steps need to take place - -
(1) Twilio function looks at specific Airtable base and finds records for date (today's date)
(2) Function looks at response body
(3) Function compares response body to expected value and returns specific message (from airtable base) if aligned
(4) Function send different specific message (from airtable base) if not aligned

Attached is an image of my airtable base.

Here's the function code - -

```
    const airtable = require("airtable");
const twilio = require("twilio");

exports.handler = function (context, event, callback) {
 const base = new airtable({
   apiKey: context.AIRTABLE_API_KEY,
 }).base(context.AIRTABLE_BASE_ID);
 const twiml = new Twilio.twiml.MessagingResponse();
 const now = new Date();
 const answer = event.Body.toLowerCase();

 return base("questions")
   .select(record.get("date") === now)
   .all()
   .then((records) => {
     records.forEach((record) => {
       if (record.get("correct") === answer) {
         twiml.message(record.get("congrats"));
         callback(null, twiml);
       }
     });
     twiml.message(record.get("hint"));
     callback(null, twiml);
   })
   .catch((error) => {
     callback(error);
   });
};
```

[airtable base image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reIyX.png)

Comment: Welcome to the community! Could you elaborate a bit more on what the actual question is?

Comment: Hi @OlehRybalchenko - thank you for your reply. My question is - - how do I create a Twilio function that will send a SMS each day where the SMS payload/content is contained within a Airtable base w/ the date? See above for resources.